# SQL Server Materialized View (Indexed View) error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view, materialized-views

I'm trying to create a Materialized View using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio   14.0.17285.0. Following is the script I ended up with to achieve the same.

My plan is to create a view and create an index on top of it.

```
use data_warehouse;

--Set the options to support indexed views.  
    SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF;  
    SET ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, ARITHABORT,  
        QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, ANSI_NULLS ON;
    GO

CREATE VIEW products_yearly_v2
WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS
    SELECT  
        p.product_id AS product_id, 
        p.product_description AS product_name,
        d.order_year AS order_year,  
        SUM(s.order_total) AS sal_by_dept
    FROM   
        [data_warehouse].[dbo].orders_fact AS s
    INNER JOIN 
        [data_warehouse].[dbo].time_dimension AS d ON s.time_id = d.order_date
    INNER JOIN 
        [data_warehouse].[dbo].product_dimension AS p ON s.product_id = p.product_id
    GROUP BY 
        d.order_year, p.product_id, p.product_description;

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_V1   
    ON products_yearly_v1 (order_year, product_id);
```

I'm getting this error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure products_yearly_v2, Line 12 [Batch Start Line 7]
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CREATE'

**Update**
Added COUNT_BIG(*) in order to create the index.

```
SELECT  COUNT_BIG(*) as count_big, p.product_id as product_id, d.order_year as order_year,  sum(s.order_total) AS sal_by_dept ....
```

Removed product_description from **GROUP BY**

```
GROUP BY d.order_year,p.product_id;
```

Readded,

```
USE data_warehouse
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use 2-part names:

> [SCHEMABINDING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
>
> Binds the view to the schema of the underlying table or tables. When SCHEMABINDING is specified, the base table or tables cannot be modified in a way that would affect the view definition. The view definition itself must first be modified or dropped to remove dependencies on the table that is to be modified. **When you use SCHEMABINDING, the select_statement must include the two-part names (schema.object) of tables, views, or user-defined functions that are referenced. All referenced objects must be in the same database.**

```
USE data_warehouse
GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.products_yearly_v2
WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS 
SELECT  
    p.product_id AS product_id, 
    p.product_description AS product_name,
    d.order_year AS order_year,  
    SUM(s.order_total) AS sal_by_dept
FROM [dbo].orders_fact AS s
JOIN [dbo].time_dimension AS d ON s.time_id = d.order_date
JOIN [dbo].product_dimension AS p ON s.product_id = p.product_id
GROUP BY d.order_year, p.product_id, p.product_description;
GO

-- index on products_yearly_v2 not products_yearly_v1
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_V2
   ON dbo.products_yearly_v2 (order_year, product_id);
```